# django model orm, a relationship query issue, hard to describe it

Tags: mysql, django, orm

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16,default='')

class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16,default='')
```

now I want to select all the Topics and the last post for the each topic.

like this:

1、 topic1　　　　　　last post for topic1

2、 topic2　　　　　　last post for topic2

3、 topic3　　　　　　last post for topic3

how should I construct the orm query ，and it should be only one sql query string.

Or the raw sql string please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raw sql:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT
  `post`.`topic_id` AS `topic_id`,
  `post`.`id` AS `id`,
  `post`.`time` AS `time`,
  `post`.`name` AS `name`
FROM `post` ORDER BY `time` DESC) AS `temp`
inner join `topic` on `topic_id` = `topic`.`id`
GROUP BY `topic_id`
ORDER BY `time` DESC;
```

is there any orm expression can do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about making it a property on `Topic`. Like this:

```
@property
def last_post(self):
    Post.objects.filter(topic=self).annotate(max_time=Max('time')).get(time=F('max_time'))
```

Then you can do this on a topic:

```
topic = Topic.objects.first()
topic.last_post
```

Comment: for one topic and the last post for the topic selection , your suggestion generate at least 2 query sql string .
And I want select many topics and each topic's last post .  in one sql string!

Comment: given one topic and query it's last post, your answer can do it .
But I want to get all topics and the last post for each topic